# AWS Api Gateway and Cognito on Android - Error 401

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm having problems integrating Cognito with ApiGateway.
First I SignIn with Cognito, not problems there, I get all the tokens.
Then I have to make a call to API Gateway. I'm using the auto-generated SDK for Android.
I'm following the example here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html but I always get the same error.

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                    context,
                    CognitoConstants.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                    CognitoConstants.REGION);

String token = cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();

Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
            logins.put(CognitoConstants.LOGIN_MAP_KEY, token);
            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
                    .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

client = factory.build(ExampleAPIClient.class);
client.exampleApi1AccountsGet();
```

The result is:

```
ApiClientException com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: {"message":"Unauthorized"}
(Service: BancarAPIClient; Status Code: 401; Error Code: null; Request ID: 3679cd4b-eefc-11e6-9d00-f99040a8ed67)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android code you have there is getting credentials from a Cognito Identity Pool, which isn't the same thing as a Cognito User Pool.

I'm not sure which one you want to use, but if the Android code is correct and you want to do signin via Twitter/FB/etc. (which is Identity Pool), you will want to set the `AuthorizationType` on your API Gateway Methods to `AWS_IAM`. It looks like the API is probably set up with a Cognito Authorizer which is meant for the User Pools feature.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I was setting the credentials for the Cognito Identity Pool.
Actually, I just needed to set the heather with the UserPool token, but I couldn't find out how, since the generated SDK is not very flexible.
Turned out that there was a problem from the backend, with a miss configuration. After it was fixed, the generated SDK added this param in the method 
(@Parameter(
    name = "Authorization",
    location = "header")
and voila!