# Generated aws gateway android sdk with cognito authorization not having authorisation paramenter

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I created AWS gateway API using chalice, using Cognito as the authorizer.

I am able to successfully login to the app using Cognito.

I am trying to access the APIs from the android app using generated AWS gateway SDK. But the generated client doesn't have param in the method (@Parameter( name = "Authorization", location = "header"))

I am able to call the APIs using postman by manually adding Authorization key and token(from the android app) in the header.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145091/aws-api-gateway-and-cognito-on-android-error-401/47631867#47631867), its mentioned that by adding some missing configuration we can generate the SDK properly. But I am not able to find the missing config.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Authorization` as one of the parameters in the `Method`, then deploy the API to a stage. After you deploy the API, you can generate the Android SDK from the stage.

In the new generated Android SDK, you should be able to have param in the method (@Parameter( name = "Authorization", location = "header")).

#### How to add a parameters in the `Method`

```
aws apigateway put-method --rest-api-id <value> \
                          --resource-id <value> \
                          --http-method <value> \
                          --api-key-required \
                          --request-parameters "method.request.header.Authorization=true"
```